# How can I write this MYSQL query without using UNION?

Tags: mysql, union

I'd like to do a single query on one table without using UNION

Here are the two queries that I need to combine.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 WHERE field4 != 'condition1' AND feild3 >= 'condition2' ORDER BY field3 ASC LIMIT 20;
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1 WHERE field4 != 'condition1' AND feild3 < 'condition2' ORDER BY field3 DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Basically, I'm trying to get 20 records above a certain record (ordered by field3, not the id), and 5 records below it, without grabbing the record itself in the results.

The trick is, I can't use UNION.

Comment: If you use >= and <=, you may get a duplicate row. Is it what you want?

Comment: Is this homework? What other reason would you have for prohibiting `union`?

Comment: @St.Woland:  You're right.  I've edited the example to show >= and <.

@Jørn:  That's pretty funny.  Actually, I'm trying to construct a query in the CakePHP framework, and UNION isn't natively supported.  I'm updating an old legacy application that simply ran two seperate queries.

Comment: CakePHP Models have a query method - http://book.cakephp.org/view/456/query - that you can pass SQL statements to.

Comment: Very true, dr.  But then it won't return any dependent models.  I'm looking at the documentation for subqueries.

Comment: @Stephen: Have you tried your accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following -

```
select a.*, b.*
from (select field1, field2, field3 
      from table1 
      where field4 != 'condition1' 
        and feild3 >= 'condition2' 
      order by field3 ASC 
      limit 20) a, 
     (select field1, field2, field3 
      from table1 
      where field4 != 'condition1' 
        and feild3 < 'condition2' 
      order my field3 desc
      limit 5) b
```

Comment: Aren't you joining subquery `a` and subquery `b` without condition? This would return a lot more rows than expected.

Comment: This looks good.

Using subqueries in cakePHP is difficult work.  I wanted to avoid using $this->Model->query, but oh well.